# How to convert a sparse vector to dense in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a sparse vector:

```
(453,[0,4,11,16,39,56,109],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

and I need to convert it into dense vector (should be able to see all 453 values).

How to do that in Scala Spark?

Comment: I figured that there is toDense function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done by using [SparseVector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector)'s `toDense` method:

```
val sv = Vectors.sparse(5, Array(0, 3), Array(1.5, -1.5))
sv.toDense
// res0: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector = [1.5,0.0,0.0,-1.5,0.0]
```